# 3d development in C# possible options?

Tags: c#, opengl, 3d, opentk

I need to build an interactive 3D graphics tool where users will be able to move meshes around and visualize them from different angles, zoom in, zoom out, i.e. the usual renderer interactivity. The choice of the language is C# .NET. The goal is to make this commercially available. I have looked at a few options, but as I am new to C#, I am not able to decide:

1) OpenTK: http://www.opentk.com/

2) TrueVision: http://www.truevision3d.com/  (But not available free)

What is the most popularly used 3D graphics wrapper or library in C# for beginners?

Comment: wouldn't opengl suffice?

Comment: And what's the problem? Or in other words: What exactly do you want? Right now you're saying `I want to make vegetable soup, should I use potatoes or carrots?`

Comment: Or you could just use Blender and Python to script what you need.

Comment: You may want to give http://www.componentsource.com/products/eyeshot-professional/index-fr-eur.html a try.

Comment: I have rephrased my question

Comment: Depending if you want a complete engine which already does a lot of work for you, or if you want to have total control thus the most amount of work. If its the later i would vote for [SlimDX](http://slimdx.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need something simple and free to start, look at the **[Helix Toolkit](http://helixtoolkit.codeplex.com/)**.

It is a opensource library that makes 3D dev in WPF a pleasure.

Because it uses WPF, it integrates smoothly with plain windows applications, WinForms or WPF. It is especially designed for simple application that uses 3D.

You can see in the demos that it includes prebuild components to help the user to move cameras around a scene, and to move and rotate primitives directly in a model.